# Matlab apply function on the vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I am a newbie in Matlab

I have a vector of 0 and 1 values. In addition I have two function, the first one for 0 values and the second one for 1 values.

```
v = [1;0;1;0;0;1]
function for0
function for1
```

The question is how can I apply these functions on the elements of the vector, depending on the element of vector. On 1 values I want to apply *for1* and on 0 values I want to apply *for0*.

These functions apply different probability distributions on the values and the typr of distribution depends on the value either 0 or 1.

Thank you

Comment: If you describe your two functions you'll get much better solutions...

Comment: @Dan, functions just probability distribution with different parameters.What I want is to get a random number from distribution A if value is 0 and from distribution B if value is 1.

Comment: Please provide the functions - it's not clear at all from your question what format they expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create two index variables, i0 and i1 where:

```
i0 = find(v==0);
i1 = find(v==1);
```

Only pass v(i0) to function for0 and only pass v(i1) to function for1.
Then combine the two outputs back into v in the same order like so:

```
out0 = for0(v(i0));
out1 = for1(v(i1));
v(i0) = out0;
v(i1) = out1;
```